# Electron detect if there is a screen recording

Tags: javascript, electron, screen-recording

What i am searching is if there is a way to ask the OS (either Mac or Windows) if the screen is actively being recorded by another program. Is there a way in Electron to get that kind of information from the OS?

Comment: probably not, other than grabbing all processes and comparing them with a list of all known recording software.. also recording screen though VNC / teamviewer etc is possible

Answer (score 0):

mainWindow.setContentProtection(true);

Prevents the window contents from being captured by other apps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).